# Getting rid of ugly casts

Tags: java, casting

**Add.java**

```
public class Add implements Value, Reducible{
Value left;
Value right;
public Add(Value left, Value right){
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return (left + " + " + right);
}

@Override
public Value reduce(Machine environment) {
    Value val = new Add(left, right);
    if(left instanceof Reducible){
        ((Add)val).left = ((Reducible) ((Add)val).left).reduce(environment);
    }
    else if(right instanceof Reducible){
        ((Add)val).right = ((Reducible) ((Add)val).right).reduce(environment);
    }else{
        val = new VNumber(((VNumber)((Add)val).left).getValue() + ((VNumber)((Add)val).right).getValue());
    }
    return val;
}
```

}

**Value.java**

```
public interface Value {
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

**Reducible.java**

```
public interface Reducible {
public abstract Value reduce(Machine environment);
}
```

Add.reduce is really ugly. It's perfect code that follows regulations, but it's almost unreadable. Is there a way to get rid of those ugly casts?

Comment: Can you give us some more context here? What's `val`? What's `left`? What are `Reducible` and `Add`?

Comment: I've edited for more context.

Comment: You could start by making val as Add and not "Value".

Comment: I would do that, except for in the else block it has to be a `VNumber` which also implements value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really making life hard for yourself. For a start you already have 'left' and 'right': you don't need to keep getting them back out of 'val'. Secondly, you shouldn't pre-create a new Add() when you're not going to use it in one case out of three, and when you don't have the correct arguments yet.

Try it this way:

```
public Value reduce(Machine environment) {
    if(left instanceof Reducible){
        return new Add(((Reducible)left).reduce(environment), right);
    }
    if(right instanceof Reducible){
        return new Add(left, ((Reducible)right).reduce(environment));
    }
    return new VNumber(((VNumber)left).getValue() + ((VNumber)right).getValue());
}
```

E&OE. But I would look very hard at using Generics here. And surely there's a missing case where both 'left' and 'right' are Reducible?

Comment: There isn't a missing case, because this method is called over and over again. But this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Adding the missing case would reduce the number of calls surely? Don't recurse any more than you really need to.

Comment: I am baffled by the downvote here. Explanation?